# Prevent script from running with jQuery / Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

Is there any way of preventing some script from running with jQuery?

For example if the website has HTML:

```
<script src="annoyingscript.js"></script>
```

Is there any possibility to trigger .remove() for that script-tag before Firefox runs the script or does anything with it ?

Basically I wish to create similar behaviour that adblock does, but I'm using Greasemonkey instead.

Comment: Is this for your own content, or for pages you are just visiting with your browser?

Comment: Greasemonkey on Firefox can do this, but AdBlock is much: better, faster, easier for this kind of blocking.

Comment: @BrockAdams, i would hate to use two tools to fix 1 site. Much easier if it was just GM script that user had to install. Looks like there is GM solution though!